# Combine arrays with conditions in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a class `People` with three properties

```
class People
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :age
end
```

And I have two arrays:

```
a = [p1, p2]
b = [p3, p4]
```

Is there any easy way to combine these two arrays in a new array and remove the item with a condition like:

```
p1.first_name + p1.last_name == p3.first_name + p3.last_name
```

And after that all the item should be belong to array `a`

For example

```
p1.first_name = "Ada"
p1.last_name = "Wang"
p1.age = 28

p2.first_name = "Leon"
p2.last_name = "S"
p2.age = 28

p3.first_name = "Ada"
p3.last_name = "Wang"
p3.age = 18

p4.first_name = "Mario"
p4.last_name = "M"
p4.age = 80
```

the result should be [p1] the 28 years old Ada.Wang

Comment: In your condition you compare `p1`'s name to `p3`'s name. What about `p2` and `p4`? Could you give a more complete example with actual data and show the expected output?

Comment: @Shaggon do you want the result to be an array of persons with no duplicate first_name last_name ?

Comment: Yes. I want a result with no duplicate first_name last_name and all the item should be belong to array a. The result should be like  `[p1]` because p2 have duplicate first_name last_name with p3 and p4 is inside array b, so only p1 is what I want

Comment: Thanks stenfan and steenslag. I found the result I want is `(b + a) - (b + a).uniq { |e| e.first_name && e.last_name }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your point, but maybe this is a possible option.

```
c = a + b
c.uniq! { |e| e.first_name && e.last_name }
```

Call [Array#uniq!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) with a block on `c` which is the [concatenation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-2B) of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I found what I want from your comment. It is  `(b + a) - (b + a).uniq { |e| e.first_name && e.last_name }`

Answer (score 0):

If arrays a and b themselves do not contain people with matching first and last names then this would work:

```
b.each_with_index do |p, i|
  if !(b[i].first_name == a[i].first_name and b[i].last_name == a[i].last_name)
    a.push(p) # as people p does not contain the same first/last names as a it can now be added to a
  end
end
```

To check for other fields simply replace first_name / last_name with other variables.